# Having trouble finding the Laurent Series Expansion of $f(z)=\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}$ on the region $0<|z-2|<R$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm just not sure how to finish out this problem.

This is how the problem was given:

> Find the Laurent Series Expansion for $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}$ on the region $0<|z-2|<R$.

I can see it has a pole at $z_{0}=2$ of order $n=2$.

I understand we can write the Laurent Series for $0<|z-z_{0}|<R$ of a pole of order $n$ as the following:

$\displaystyle \frac{a_{-n}}{(z-z_{0})^{n}} + \frac{a_{-(n-1)}}{(z-z_{0})^{n-1}} + \cdots +\frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_{0})} + a_{0} + a_{1}(z-z_{0}) + a_{2}(z-z_{0})^{2} + a_{3}(z-z_{0})^{3} +\cdots$

With $z_{0}=2\text{, and }n=2$ we would find the following Laurent Series:

$\displaystyle \frac{a_{-2}}{(z-2)^{2}} + \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-2)} + a_{0} + a_{1}(z-2) + a_{2}(z-2)^{2} + a_{3}(z-2)^{3}\cdots$

If I understand correctly we stop at $-2$ on the negative side because all $n<-2$ returns a zero for that coefficient.  However, on the positive side we take $n\to \infty$ so we can rewrite the series with $z_{0}=2\text{, and }n=2$ plugged in and get the following:

$$\displaystyle \frac{a_{-2}}{(z-2)^{2}} + \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-2)} + a_{0} + a_{1}(z-2) + a_{2}(z-2)^{2} + a_{3}(z-2)^{3}\cdots$$
$$=\sum_{n=-2}^{-1}a_{n}(z-2)^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-2)^{n}$$

This is where I get confused.  I see in my text that for a simple pole we can find:

using $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}$

(I included the simple pole because the book explicitly states this is $a_{-1}$, but I know this does not apply to a pole of order $n$)

$\displaystyle a_{-1}=\text{Res}(f(z),z_{0})=\lim\limits_{z\to z_{0}}(z-z_{0})f(z)$

and for the Residue at a Pole of order $n$ we have

$\displaystyle \text{Res}(f(z),z_{0})=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z\to z_{0}}\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z-z_{0})f(z)\right]\right)$

But what coefficient is the Residue of a Pole of order $n$?  $a_{-2}\text{ or }a_{-1}$? and what if the pole had a greater order, $n>2$, resulting in many more $a_{-n}$ terms?

Then, how do I find $a_{n}\text{ for }n\geq 0$?

EDIT:
The textbook I reference throughout this post is

> Complex Analysis A First Course with Applications by Dennis Zill & Patrick Shanahan, 3ed

EDIT 2 using information from @user317176's response:

I found $a_{-1}$ using the residue theorem

$$a_{-1}=\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}},z_{0}=2\right)$$
$$a_{-1}=\frac{1}{(2-1)!}\lim\limits_{z\to 2}\left(\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}\left[(z-2)^{2}\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}\right]\right)$$
$$a_{-1}=\frac{1}{1!}\lim\limits_{z\to 2}\left(\frac{d^{1}}{dz^{1}}\left[(z-2)^{2}\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}\right]\right)$$
$$a_{-1}=\lim\limits_{z\to 2}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\left[ze^{z}\right]\right)$$
$$a_{-1}=\lim\limits_{z\to 2}\left(e^{z}+ze^{z}\right)$$
$$a_{-1}=e^{2}+2e^{2}$$
$$a_{-1}=3e^{2}$$

still trying to figure out how to work out $a_{-2}$ and $a_{n\geq 0}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to write this as a Laurent Series.  I think I sent people down the wrong path focusing on the coefficients using residue theorem and whatnot.  Both responses were on the right path apart from the residue stuff but not quite there based on what I found, and I've tested my series against the original function, using Maple symbolic software.

For the problem:

> Find the Laurent Series Expansion for $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}$ on the region $0<|z-2|<R$.

Start by manipulating $f(z)$ into a desirable form, which other answers were close to but it is not clear why one would need $z\to(z+2-2)$ in the numerator, so I left off that manipulation and achieved a correct series expansion.
$\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{ze^{z}}{(z-2)^{2}}=\frac{ze^{z+2-2}}{(z-2)^{2}}=\frac{ze^{2}(e^{z-2})}{(z-2)^{2}}$

Then, for $\displaystyle e^{z}=1+\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{k}}{k!}+\cdots=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}$

We can write $\displaystyle e^{z-2}=1+\frac{z-2}{1!}+\frac{(z-2)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(z-2)^{k}}{k!}+\cdots=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^{k}}{k!}$

Then, writing $\displaystyle \frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)^{2}}(e^{z-2})$, and expanding the exponential:

$$\frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)^{2}}\left(1+\frac{z-2}{1!}+\frac{(z-2)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(z-2)^{k}}{k!}+\cdots\right)$$

Allowing us to write the expanded form of this series as:

$$\frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)^{2}}+\frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)}+\frac{ze^{2}}{2!}+\frac{ze^{2}(z-2)}{3!}+\frac{ze^{2}(z-2)^{2}}{4!}+\cdots$$

As a side note the Principal part is found to be:

$$\frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)^{2}}+\frac{ze^{2}}{(z-2)}$$

And the Analytic part to be:

$$\frac{ze^{2}}{2!}+\frac{ze^{2}(z-2)}{3!}+\frac{ze^{2}(z-2)^{2}}{4!}+\cdots$$

Finally, this Laurent Series can be condensed to the following:

$$\sum\limits_{k=-2}^{\infty}\frac{ze^{2}(z-2)^{k}}{(k+2)!}$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{ze^z}{(z-2)^2}&=\frac{(z-2+2)e^{(z-2+2)}}{(z-2)^2}\\\\
&=e^2\left[\left(\frac{ e^{z-2}}{z-2}\right)+2\left(\frac{e^{z-2}}{(z-2)^2}\right)\right]
\end{align}$$

Now use the Taylor series $e^{z-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-2)^n}{n!}$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Are you implying:  factor out the $e^{z-2}$ and run a Taylor series on it multiplied by where it factored out of?  so, $ e^2\left[\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{2}{(z-2)^2}\right]\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^n}{n!}$
If so, how does this deal with the pole?  is this saying $a_{-1}=e^2$ and $a_{-2}=2e^2$?

Comment: Yes.  You have it now.  Well done.  But be careful on $a_{-1}$.  There are two contributions.

Comment: how did you do that partial fraction decomp? tbh thats the obly part im stuck on..

Comment: Well, the numerator has $z=(z-2)+2$ .  So, divide by $(z-2)^2$.  This gives $\frac1{z-2}$ and $\frac2{(z-2)^2}$ parts.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Taking $\displaystyle e^2\left[\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{2}{(z-2)^2}\right]\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^n}{n!}$ from your comment to another answer.

$\displaystyle e^2\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^{n-1}}{n!}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(z-2)^{n-2}}{n!}\right]$

Re-index
$\displaystyle \displaystyle e^2\left[\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^{n}}{(n+1)!}+ \sum_{n=-2}^{\infty}\frac{2(z-2)^{n}}{(n+2)!}\right]$

$\displaystyle 2e^2(z-2)^{-2} + e^2\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+4)(z-2)^{n}}{(n+2)!}$

$\displaystyle c_{-2} = 2e^2, c_{-1} = 3e^2$

To follow up on the method in the original post.

Our general Laurent series
$\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_\limits{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n (z-a)^n$

Around a contour that includes $a$

$\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz = (2\pi i) c_{-1}$

We can find the general term of the Laurent series if we multiply the function by the appropriate factor $(z-a)^k$

In this example:

$\displaystyle c_{-1} = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac {ze^{z}}{(z-2)^2}$

$\displaystyle c_{n} = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac {ze^{z}}{(z-2)^2}(z-2)^{-(n+1)}$

$\displaystyle c_{-2} = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac {ze^{z}}{(z-2)} = 2e^2$

From the Cauchy integral formula.
$\displaystyle c_n = \frac {1}{n!}\frac {d}{dz^{n+1}} ze^{z}|_2$

$\displaystyle c_{-1} \frac {d}{dz} ze^{z}|_{2} = (1+z)e^{z}|_2 = 3e^2$

For $n\ge 1$

$\displaystyle c_n = \frac {n+4}{n!} e^{2}$

This approach is more cumbersome but more generalizable.

Comment: At the moment, it is not.  I was clarifying the question that the OP put on your post.  However, I am filling out this answer to further differentiate it, so it will stand alone on its own merit.

Comment: I see.  I suppose it's too long for a comment.  So (+1)

Comment: I'm reviewing everything now.  Thank you.

Comment: I hope you dont mind i added "\displaystyle" to the lines with fractions and larger symbols to make things larger and easier to read.

Comment: I have a couple of questions but its too much for a comment so I'll just put them in an "answer response"

Comment: @EvanHowington I would suggest you edit your original post rather than pose additional questions as an answer.

Comment: @user317176 thats what I'm doing.  I'm just trying to match up what you're doing with what is in my textbook.  I'm recognizing this things as Laurents Theorem equated to Cauchy integral formula for derivatives.. So it seems like that is the setup for $n\geq0$ but when the negative values of n appears to just use the residue theorem.  I'm stuck because the book only discusses $a_1$

Comment: Ok, i figured out $a_{-1} $ using your response and updated the question, and now i'm trying to figure out how to get $a_{-2}$ since I'm not sure.  I see the integral you have for it but now sure how it gives $2e^{2}$.  Is it just residue of a simple pole?  if so, how did we get there?  by that factor of $(z-2)^{n}$?  also, where does that factor come from because I'm not seeing it anywhere in my textbook.

Comment: for $c_{-2}$ it looks like the denominator would be $(z-2)^{2+1}$ and when you multiply through by $(z-2)^{-(-2)}$ you end up with a denominator of $(z-2)$ and doing the Res of that would be Res($\frac{ze^{z}}{z-2},2$) which would result in $2e^{2}$

Comment: Thanks, I made a small edit.  To find the $c_{-1}$ coefficient we don't multiply by anything.  So, to find the $c_{-2}$ component we multiply by $(z-2)$

Comment: I guess i'm just confused about it because I don't see that method anywhere in my book, multiplying  by a factor of the denominator to the power of -(n+1).  I suppose this only works for $n\leq -1$?   I'll just chalk it up to memory and/or ask my prof about it later this week.